# Angular event binding not working when using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, ngfor

Right now I have a relatively simple template in my angular controller,

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" [attr.aria-labelledby]="item.name" *ngIf="item.children">
  <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let child of item.children; let last = last" (click)="child.action">{{child.name}} <hr *ngIf="!last"></button>
</div>
```

However my (click) event binding disappears from the DOM when everything is compiled. If I change the button to a link element and change `(click)` to `[href]` it works so.

Appreciate any help, just getting to grips with Angular2 :)

**Edit:**
I apologise, I had a moment of madness (stupidity)...

Comment: Obviously nothing will happen because you never invoke anything here `(click)="child.action"`

Comment: @dfsq I've updated the question which hopefully explains better what the issue is.

Comment: And what did you expect should be rendered? There will no attributes like `onclick` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean

```
(click)="child.action()"
```

or

```
(click)="child.action($event)"
```

otherwise it won't be called.

Comment: Sorry I'll provide more information to my original question as that isn't the issue :)

Comment: Was just a typo :D